# Word 2019 option stopped working

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, bug

I was tinkering with Word 2019's options about recent documents.

I always disliked that everytime I open a file I have it shown when I start Word, so I initially set, both "Show this number of Recent Documents" and "Show this number of unpinned Recent Folders" in Advanced Options, to 0.
Recently though, I came to like them more so I went back and reset them to the default 50, I realized then that the option in-between called "Quickly access this number of Recent Documents" was set to 1 instead of the default 4.

I know for a fact that the default is 4 because in every other Office application I own (even those I never even opened once before) it is set to 4, but everytime I try (only in Word) to set it back to 4 it remains at 1.

I tried the same thing with Excel for example: I set it to 1 and it remained 1, then set it to 4 and it remained 4. I also tried checking the box next to it that enables it (it's disabled by default and I don't even want it enabled) but it produces the same result. I tried deleting (in order for the application to restore them anew) the registers responsible for those options, but nothing changed.

What could have caused such behavior? And how do I make that option work again?

[edit] I even tried to fully uninstall and reinstall Office's suite but the problem stayed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by my own.
Basically I uninstalled the complete suite of Office again, rebooted, and then deleted the complete folder of Word from the registers (you can find its location on Microsoft's site about resetting any office application's settings) instead of just deleting a single folder at a time to find where this option is (I tried deleting the subfolders Options Data and Common [this one is not a subfolder of Word though] probably the option is in another subfolder that I haven't tried to delete and would save time while also preserving your existing installation, but I can't be bothered to find it).

Then reinstalled the suite and voilà, it's working again, I can change it to whatever number and it's gonna remain that number.

[edit] I can change it to whatever number... except 1, if I put 1 it gets stuck again (this happens only in Word). At this point it might as well be a bug, so I'll leave it at that.